# I can't create an ordered form

Tags: html, css

I want to create a registration form with the following order on each line:

label input  label input 
label input  label input

I wrote some code and managed to get the order right
 The problem is that the labels and therefore the text inside them are not aligned between the different lines and the same goes for the inputs.

```html
<div class="container" align="center">
  <div align="center">
    <h1> New patient </h1>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>

  <form action="/action_page.php">


    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="fname">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your 
       name..">



      <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last 
       name..">
    </div>



    <div class="input-group">
      <label class="label">Gender</label>

      <label class="radio-container m-r-45">Maschio
            <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="gender" required 
         value="M">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
      <label class="radio-container">Femmina
            <input type="radio" name="gender" required value="F">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>


      <label class="label">Birthday</label>

      <input class="input--style-4 js-datepicker" type="text" name="birthday" required>

    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="cf">Fiscal Code</label>
      <input type="text" id="cf" name="cf" placeholder="Fiscal Code..">




      <input type="button" value="Calculate">
    </div>



    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="fname">Via</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your 
       name..">



      <label for="lname">Civico</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last 
         name..">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="fname">Citta</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your 
        name..">



      <label for="lname">CAP</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last 
        name..">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="fname">Father's name</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your  
        name..">




      <input type="submit" value="Add">
  </form>

  </div>
```

Comment: Are you using css in your file? If yes, please provide it.

Comment: desired output if you can show us what you trying to achieve. I quiet not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.left-align-field{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;


}


.right-align-field{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;

}
```

```html
<div class="container" align="center">
  <div align="center">
    <h1> New patient </h1>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>

  <form action="/action_page.php">


    <div class="input-group">
     <div class="left-align-field">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your 
       name..">
     </div>


     <div class="right-align-field">
        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last 
       name..">
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="input-group">
    
     <div class="left-align-field">    
        <label class="label">Gender</label>

        <label class="radio-container m-r-45">Maschio
            <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="gender" required 
         value="M">
         <span class="checkmark"></span>
            
         </label>
        <label class="radio-container">Femmina
            <input type="radio" name="gender" required value="F">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
         </label>
  </div>


     <div class="right-align-field">
        <label class="label">Birthday</label>

        <input class="input--style-4 js-datepicker" type="text" name="birthday" required>
  </div>
    </div>



    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="left-align-field"> 
        <label for="cf">Fiscal Code</label>
        <input type="text" id="cf" name="cf" placeholder="Fiscal Code..">




        <input type="button" value="Calculate">
       </div>
    </div>



    <div class="input-group">
            <div class="left-align-field"> 
      <label for="fname">Via</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your 
       name..">
</div>

        <div class="right-align-field"> 


      <label for="lname">Civico</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last 
         name..">
    </div>

</div>

    <div class="input-group">
            <div class="left-align-field"> 
      <label for="fname">Citta</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your 
        name..">
</div>
        <div class="right-align-field"> 


      <label for="lname">CAP</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last 
        name..">
    </div>
<div>


    <div class="input-group">
            <div class="left-align-field"> 
      <label for="fname">Father's name</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your  
        name..">
</div>

        <div class="right-align-field"> 

      <input type="submit" value="Add">
      </div>
  </form>

  </div>
```